# Python 101 string slicing

Tags: string, python-3.x, slice

I am complete newb at python :P.  How can I return just the third word of a string using string slicing?  Am I close with:

```
splitString = myString.split()
print splitString[2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to use split, then yes you are.  Slicing is only slightly different from indexing:

```
index = '12345'[2]

slice = '12345'[1:3]
```

Hopefully that hint helps.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Slicing does not recognize *words*. The usual definition of a word is (simplified) *something separated from the rest by spaces*. Slicing does not allow you to find the spaces. As Ethan wrote, it just gives you a substring from the index range. Your own approach with .split() a good one.

If the task is to use slicing to get the word, you have to find the positions of the word first. For that, you can use `str.find`. You must be careful because one or more whitespaces mean a single word separator.

Comment: I'm very sure `str.split` is a better alternative for finding the words separated by spaces than `str.find`.

Comment: @OdraEncoded: ... unless it is a homework and usage of slicing is required.